# Sending auto response to organizer when calendar invite is accepted

Tags: java, icalendar

I am sending email with ics file attached. When attendee accept the calendar automatically mail should go to organizer as acknowledgement. But when attendee accept it will get added to calendar but mail is not getting sent to organizer.

Here is my icalFileContent which will be used in java code

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//xxxxx //Calendar Event//EN
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:54131
DTSTAMP:xxxxx
DTSTART:xxxxx
DTEND:xxxx
SUMMARY:Summary
ORGANIZER:MAILTO:xx@xx.com
ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;RSVP=TRUE:MAILTO:x@x.com
SEQUENCE:0
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Automated mail should trigger to organizer on accept of calendar invite

Here is my Java Code :

```
public void sendTestEvent(final MailAudit mail) {
    MimeMessagePreparator preperator = new MimeMessagePreparator() {
        public void prepare(MimeMessage mimeMessage) throws Exception {
            mimeMessage.addHeaderLine("method=REQUEST");
            mimeMessage.addHeaderLine("charset=UTF-8");
            mimeMessage.addHeaderLine("component=VEVENT");
            mimeMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress("xx@xx.com"));
            mimeMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("xx@xx.com"));
            mimeMessage.setSubject("Calendar");
            BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-Class", "urn:content-  classes:calendarmessage");
                    messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID", "calendar_message");
                messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(
                        new ByteArrayDataSource("icsFileContent", "text/calendar")));// very important
                    Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
            mimeMessage.setContent(multipart);

        }
    };
    mailSender.send(preperator);
}
```

Comment: You did not specify which client you are using when accepting the invite.

Comment: I am trying in gmail..